# Jquery slider not working in my ASP.NET Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having a problem where the Jquery Slider isn't working ( rendering to look like a actual slider ) , I can't see any problems in my code to as of why it wont actually work so I have no idea where the problem lands. My code is below , excuse me if this is a really simple / "noob" mistake but I am new to using Jquery.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MachineSweepLite.aspx.vb"              Inherits="Production_MachineSweepLite" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title>Checks</title>
 <link  href="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js">

 </script>
</head>
<body background="../icons/Building-Confidence-logo.jpg" onload="init();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>   
<label for="quesTion">Input Question Here:</label>
    <select name="quesTion" id="quesTion" data-role="slider">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything actually wrong with this to see why it will not work?

Comment: none , just doesn't appear as it is intended to appear.

Comment: doesn't a slider need to be an `<input>` tag with attribute `type='range'` ? not sure if it will work on a select type

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/index.htmlshouldn't u be using the jqueryUI

Comment: @fnostro I have literally no idea friend & AJ that link is broken.

Comment: try this link: [jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/)

Comment: I have used that methodology , even when i use the $('select').slider(); in my script tags nothing changes it just appears as a drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a reference to the JQuery framework...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title>Checks</title>
 <link  href="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <!--you must include this reference-->
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js">

 </script>
</head>
<body background="../icons/Building-Confidence-logo.jpg" onload="init();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>   
<label for="quesTion">Input Question Here:</label>
    <select name="quesTion" id="quesTion" data-role="slider">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For reference, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/KKE2G/) a jsfiddle of the slider.